# How to remove the stop words from text file without removing white space

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, stop-words

I have to remove stop words from text file containing 50K tweets . when i run this code ,it removes the stopwords successfully but at the same time it removes white space also. I want white space in the text.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import codecs

import nltk

stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))

writeFile = codecs.open("outputfile", "w", encoding='utf-8')

with codecs.open("inputfile", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
           line = f.read()
           tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
           tokens = [w for w in tokens if not w in stopset]
           for token in tokens:
               writeFile.write(token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write, write whitespace where you want whitespace. In your concrete case, a newline after each token would seem suitable, since you are killing all other formatting already.  Using `print` instead of `write` does that without requiring you to mark up with an explicit newline:

```
from __future__ import print_function  # if you're on Python 2
# ...
for token in tokens:
    print(token, file=writeFile)
```

Alternatively, if you want spaces instead of newlines, put spaces.
If you have a limited amount of tokens, you could just

```
print(' '.join(tokens), file=writeFile)
```

but this will eat up a gob of memory to join the string together before printing, so a loop over the tokens would be more economical.  But because you are processing a line at a time, joining is probably good enough, and will get you the tokens from one input line together on one output line.

If you have a large amount of tokens per line, and want to loop over them for memory efficiency, a common idiom is to declare a separator which is initially empty:

```
sep = ''
for token in tokens:
    writeFile.write('{}{}'.format(sep, token))  # str.format(): py >= 2.6
    sep=' '
writeFile.write('\n')
```

Comment: Then you will end up with one really long line, but more power to you.

Comment: Put spaces between the words.

Comment: Its not feasible because this file has more than 50,000 lines